# W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject error how it's can be Fixed

Tags: java, android, response

I'm following the steps in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sKCdqCuFFFk) video.

And I'm having :

> W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value

This is my JAVA code:

```js
public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                            boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");
                            if (success){
                                String first_name = jsonResponse.getString("first_name");
                                String last_name = jsonResponse.getString("last_name");

                                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, HomePageActivity.class);
                                intent.putExtra("first_name", first_name);
                                intent.putExtra("last_name", last_name);

                            }else {
                                AlertDialog.Builder builder= new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this);
                                builder.setMessage("Login Failed")
                                        .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                                        .create()
                                        .show();
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
```

My PHP Code:

```js
<?php

    $con = mysqli_connect("*****", "********", "********", "*********");


    
    $email = $_POST["email"];
 $password = $_POST["password"];


 $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM user WHERE email = ? AND password = ?");

 mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ss", $email, $password);
 mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);


    
    mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
 mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement, $userid, $first_name, $last_name, $email, $password);


 $response = array();
 $response["success"] = false;
 
 while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)){

        $response["success"] = true;

        $response["first_name"] = $first_name;

        $response["last_name"] = $last_name;

        $response["email"] = $email;

        $response["password"] = $password;

    }
    
    
 echo json_encode($response);

?>
```

the error from the debugging in the question above
and this is the Debug :

> at
>   com.thecreds.credsapp.LoginActivity$2$1.onResponse(LoginActivity.java:47)
>           at com.thecreds.credsapp.LoginActivity$2$1.onResponse(LoginActivity.java:43)

and still, have no idea where I went wrong I followed the steps and it's not working.

Comment: Your HTTP request is returning HTML, not JSON.

Comment: can you tell me how to fix it ? I'm really a beginner

Comment: Presumably there is some problem with the HTTP request that you are making. Since you seem to control the server, check your server logs for clues.

Comment: <b>Warning</b>:  mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused in <b>/storage/ssd3/155/9694155/public_html/Login.php</b> on line <b>3</b><br />
    <br />
    <b>Warning</b>:  mysqli_prepare() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean given in <b>/storage/ssd3/155/9694155/public_html/Login.php</b> on line <b>11</b><br />
    <br />

Comment: Presumably, your problem is with your PHP. I suggest that you ask a separate Stack Overflow question, where you provide your PHP and the output, and where the question is tagged for PHP developers to help you.

Comment: okay i will thank you